# The best way to make Loopback GET query parameters safe?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using Loopback 3.x with loopback-connector-mongodb 3.x

Apparently, many built-in endpoints can take a filter parameter which can be defined as JSON and it may contain complex filter conditions like order, where, skip etc.. For example:

```
GET /api/activities/findOne?filter={"where":{"id":1234}}
```

However, although Loopback uses an ORM, it seems the request parameters are passed to mongodb without any kind of pre-processing or escaping.
I was unable to find any Loopback API method which could help me make the value safe.
If, for example, the user puts Javascript into the where filter, or adds unsupported characters (such as null char), the app throws an exception an exits.

I'm sure I'm missing something here. What's the best way to make the value passed in filter={...} safe?
Is there a built-in API method for this?
If there isn't, are there any node module I could use?

Comment: use some schema validators like `joi` to validatte the filter passed

Comment: Thanks! Joi is cool, I'm gonna definitely use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mixin which validates the JSON you receive.

For example:

```
module.exports = function(Model, options) {
   Model.beforeRemote('find', (ctx, instance, next) => {
      // Validate the filter object
   }
}
```

Comment: yeah sounds good thank! I wrote a middleware., which is kinda similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys!

I turned off Javascript in MongoDB and wrote a little middleware to handle escaping. This is registered in middleware.json and thus it runs before every request and escapes the values.

```
  module.exports = function createEscaper(options) {
  return function queryEscape(req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.filter) {
      // escape various things and update the value..
    }
    next();
  };
}
```

But I find it really strange that neither the MongoDB connector nor Loopback itself provides any solution for this. I mean, these parameters are defined and handled in framework code. It's kinda crazy there is no built-in escaping whatsoever.